# Странный слог А. Дубровского

Tags: история-языка, стилистика

В романе Пушкина «Дубровский» повествователь,  комментируя следующее письмо, написанное одним из персонажей,

> Государь мой премилостивый,
>   Я до тех пор не намерен ехать в Покровское, пока не вышлете Вы мне псаря Парамошку с повинною; а будет моя воля наказать его или помиловать, а я терпеть шутки от Ваших холопьев не намерен, да и от Вас их не стерплю, потому что я не шут, а старинный дворянин. За сим остаюсь покорным ко услугам
>   Андрей Дубровский.

говорит:

> По нынешним понятиям об этикете письмо сие было бы весьма неприличным, но оно рассердило Кирила Петровича не странным слогом и расположением, но только своею сущностью

А интересно, как вы думаете,  в чем именно заключалась  «странность»?
Перечитываю, перечитываю, а я еще ничего особенно старомодного в сравнении с основным текстом романа в этом письме так и не нашел. Такие тонкости, похоже, мне не уловить, а ведь бывают более существенные изменения в слоге, которые даже я замечаю, ну возьми хоть сумасшедший слог, которым написано определение суда страницы через три.

Быть может, все дело в слове «премилоствый»?

Answer (score 11):

Возможно дело действительно в обращении. Они были [регламентированы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8) в зависимости от чинов и прочих заслуг. В частности, в переписке частные лица обращались следующим образом:

> ко всем частным лицам — «милостивый государь» (при обращении к высшему), «милостивый государь мой» (к равному), «государь мой» (к низшему).

Возможно перенос слова "премилостивый" в конец обращения делал его созвучным обращению "государь мой" (т.е. ставил автора выше адресата), а "премилостивый" вместо "милостивый" тоже делал правильную формулу "милостивый государь мой" размытой.

М. Ю. Лотман приводит такой пример щепетильного отношения к правильности обращения в письме:

> Вообще, этикет в письмах должен был соблюдаться с большой точностью. Известен случай, когда сенатор, приехавший с ревизией, в обращении к губернатору (а губернатор был из графов Мамоновых и славился своей гордостью) вместо положенного: «Милостивый государь!» — написал: «Милостивый государь мой!» Обиженный губернатор ответное письмо начал словами: «Милостивый государь мой, мой, мой!» — сердито подчеркнув неуместность притяжательного местоимения «мой» в официальном обращении.

Answer (score 4):

> По нынешним понятиям об этикете письмо сие было бы весьма неприличным,
>   но оно рассердило Кирила Петровича не странным слогом и расположением,
>   но только своею сущностью
>
> А интересно, как вы думаете, в чем именно заключалась «странность»?
>   Перечитываю, перечитываю, а я еще ничего особенно старомодного в
>   сравнении с основным текстом романа в этом письме так и не нашел.

Вот что странное в письме:

### Обращение.

Обращение "милостивый государь" и ему подобные были только в официальных письмах. В дружеских письмах никаких "государей" не было. Например, Дельвиг письма к Пушкину начинал "Здравия желаю Александру милому и поздравляю с Новым годом", "Поздравляем тебя, милый Пушкин, с переменой судьбы твоей" и т. д.  Также могли друга назвать "любезнейший" (например, "здравствуйте, любезнейшая и почтеннейшая Варвара Алексеевна"), а часто (даже, может быть, в большинстве случаев) обходились без обращения, сразу переходя к делу.  *Своим обращением Дубровский сразу даёт понять, что они с Троекуровым более не друзья.*

Но это далеко не всё. Теоретически, по Далю, были три обращения: "милостивый государь" к высшим, "милостивый государь мой" к равным и "государь мой" к низшим. На практике, из трёх обращений в письмах почти всегда выбирали первое. Так, например, Бекендорф в письме Пушкину называет его "милостивый государь", хотя отправитель неизмеримо выше адресата и по табели о рангах (Бекендорф был генералом от кавалерии), и по титулу (граф), и по занимаемой должности.  Словами "Милостивый государь мой" письма начинали редко, а "государь мой", кажется, никогда.

Слова "государь мой премилостивый" странные. Такого обращения не было, и звучит это как гибрид второго обращения, не очень-то вежливого, и третьего, пренебрежительного.  Да и перестановка слов - это как если бы современное письмо начать так "Иван Иванович, уважаемый, ..."

### Подпись

Под стать обращению.  В официальных письмах прощались словами "милостивый государь (с новой строки) ваш покорный слуга", иногда слегка изменёнными: ваш покорнейший слуга, вашего превосходительства всепокорнейший слуга и т.д. Пример:

```
                       Милостивый государь!
                         Николай Петрович.

Почтенное письмо ваше с приложением перстня от ее императорского величества имел
я счастие получить. Принимаю с глубочайшим благоговением и благодарностью сей
знак высокой ее милости к слабому моему таланту. Имею честь пребыть с истинным 
почтением

                                                         милостивый государь
                                                       ваш покорнейший слуга
                                                                Иван Крылов.

                           Апреля 22 дня
                               1826.
```

Была подпись "остаюсь готовым к услугам вашим" (или "вашим услугам"), например, в письме Белинского Гоголю 1842 года (не путать с их перепиской 1847 года, вошедшей в хрестоматии).  Будучи в ярости, Дубровский смешал эти две подписи, получилось опять же не вежливая подпись, а что-то странное.

### Основной текст

> Я до тех пор не намерен ехать в Покровское, пока не вышлете Вы мне
>   псаря Парамошку с повинною; а будет моя воля наказать его или
>   помиловать, а я терпеть шутки от Ваших холопьев не намерен, да и от
>   Вас их не стерплю, потому что я не шут, а старинный дворянин.

Текст не разбит на предложения и стилистически неправилен. Правильно, по-моему:

Я до тех пор не намерен ехать в Покровское, пока не вышлете Вы мне псаря Парамошку с повинною, а наказать его или помиловать, на то моя воля. Я терпеть шутки от Ваших холопьев не намерен, да и от Вас их не стерплю, потому что я не шут, а старинный дворянин.

Comment: Сложно сказать, что звучало странно во времена Пушкина, а что нет. С современной точки зрения (200 лет спустя) - все в тексте достаточно несовременно.

Comment: @VitalyOsipov - можно прочитать письма тех времён, и понять, как тогда писали. Я прочитал порядка 100 писем, в основном Пушкину, Пушкина, и в его группе общения.  Картина вырисовывается вполне ясная.